# TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to get the bot to add roles in one discord and also add a role in another discord. but I keep getting the "roles" is not defined error. I have little to no coding knowledge and most of my code is a combination of things I find on google or friends teach me, so please excuse me if it is a dumb problem with a simple solution.

```js
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.GUILD_ROLES] });
    
    module.exports = {
        
        name: 'accept',
        description: 'Adds A Player To The Whitelist',
        permissions: `ADMINISTRATOR`,
        execute(message, args, add, roles, addRole, guild) {
                
            message.delete()
    
    
            let rMember = guild.roles.cache
            message.mentions.members.first() || // `.first()` is a function.
            message.guild.members.cache.find((m) => m.user.tag === args[0]) ||
            message.guild.members;
    
    
            let role1 =
        message.guild.roles.cache.find((r) => r.id == roleID)
    
        let role2 =
        message.guild.roles.cache.find((r) => r.id == roleID)
    
        let server = client.guilds.cache.get('guild ID')
        let memberRole = server.guild.roles.get("role ID");
    
        rMember.roles.add(role1).catch((e) => console.log(e));
        rMember.roles.add(role2).catch((e) => console.log(e));
        rMember.roles.add(memberRole).catch((e) => console.log(e));
    
    
            rMember.send(`message content`);
            message.channel.send('message content')
    }};
```

The error occurs in this line:

```js
let memberRole = server.guild.roles.get("872432775330955264");
```

Comment: On which line is the error located?

Comment: @MrMythical sorry for not including that, it is on line js:17:29 so <let memberRole = server.guild.roles.get("872432775330955264");>

Comment: I don't think you need the `GUILD_MEMBER` flag to access the cache for the roles or the guilds

Answer (score 1):

```js
let server = client.guilds.cache.get('guild ID')
let memberRole = server.guild.roles.get("role ID");
```

These particular lines justify your error, in the first case you are assigning the property of a guild object to `server` by getting the guild from the cache, now you see a guild object does not have a property further named `guild` to it so your error actually rests in the next line, where you are trying to get from `server.guild` it's same as saying `guild.guild` which makes no actual sense.

Only correction you would want to make with your code would be something of this sort:

```js
let server = client.guilds.cache.get('guild ID')
let memberRole = server.roles.cache.get("role ID");
```

Comment: And if the guild isn't cached, you can use `.fetch('ID')` instead of `.cache.get`